# Selecting a collection with a dot in its name

Tags: php, mongodb

I usually select a collection by using the following method...
assuming the collection name is "fantastic" in a database called "somedb"

```
$conn = new Mongo();
$fantastic_coll = $conn->somedb->fantastic;
```

This has worked famously for me for a long time. The number of collections I am using has grown a lot and I'm trying to use dots in the collection names to organise them a little more logically.

eg.

- store.items
- store.categories
- store.coupons
- events
- events.categories

This seems to work fine in the mongodb shell, but not in php?

if I try....

```
$conn = new Mongo();
$store_coupons_coll = $conn->somedb->store.coupons;
```

and then try to save documents into the collection it doesn't like me.

if I instead use...

```
$conn = new Mongo();
$store_coupons_coll = $conn->somedb->selectCollection('store.coupons');
```

everything works as expected.
Is this the right way to do it?

- If so then I hope this helps anyone having the same trouble.
- If not then is there a short way to write the collection name?
- Is using dots in the collection name for organisation wrong to begin with?

Comment: Untested, but is there any possibility to do something like this: `$conn->somedb->{'store.coupons'}`, I mean use magic methods / variable methods ?

Comment: That appears to have worked. Will test a little more with that method.

Comment: I hope, it is reliable. Cheers.

Comment: It seems to be working after a bit of testing.

Comment: Why does this work? Does it stop PHP tripping over the dot?

Comment: the `{}` denotes a literal key between those deliminators, it basically is a way of saying to PHP to use that string as a variable in accession. However it is not infalliable, I would use the method you are at the moment really

Comment: [MongoDB::selectCollection()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.selectcollection.php) is certainly the preferred method, as Derick suggested below. In addition to the syntax @CORRUPT suggested above, you could chain `->` operators, such as `$conn->somedb->store->coupons`. That utilizes [MongoCollection::__get()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.get.php) and is actually closest to what most people do naturally in the shell (e.g. `db.foo.bar.insert(...)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred way of doing this is with:

```
$collection = $conn->somedb->selectCollection( 'store.coupons' );
```

Or if you want:

```
$collection = $conn->selectCollection( 'somedb', 'store.coupons' );
```

Comment: So my original method of... '$conn = new Mongo(); $fantastic_coll = $conn->somedb->fantastic;' ...shouldn't be used at all? Even for simple collection names? Is it just a shorthand method provided for convenience? I'd like to use the same method everytime I choose a collection, so I'm leaning towards using "selectCollection" every time.

Comment: You can do this just fine for simple collection names, just not for ones that contain PHP syntax ( the ``.`` is an operator).